# PHP export to excel

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I'm having a trouble that I can't export japanese texts to excel (xls).

I used the following codes:

```
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel;charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");     
echo $contents;
```

But in the excel file, the text changed to funny characters like this:

> ```
> Ã©Â™?Ã¥Â®ÂšÃ§Â‰? Ã£?Â¨Ã£??Ã£?Â¯Ã£??Ã£?Â£Ã£?Â†Ã£?ÂªÃ£?Â¢Ã¥??Ã§ÂŠÂ¬Ã£?Â®Ã£?ÂŒÃ¦??Ã£?
> ```
>
> Â’Ã¨??Ã£??Ã£?ÂŸÃ£?Â†Ã£?Â£Ã£??Ã£??Ã£??Ã£?? Ã¯??

Currently, I'm using hostingmanager and I tried on the different server using the same codes and there's no problem.

What could be the problem. Because of the PHP version??
Please help me.

Comment: Where do you get the contents of `$contents` from?

Comment: I get the variables from the data base and put all into that variable($contents).
$contents .= order_id"."\t"."$fname"."\t"."$lname"."\t"."$email"."\t";

Comment: Have you considered sending an actual excel payload/file, instead of just CSV disguised as it?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Warning: Headers already sent" in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/warning-headers-already-sent-in-php)

Comment: The same database on both servers?

Comment: That's called Mojibake.  What is the text supposed to say?  I think you have "sjis", not "utf-8" encoding, perhaps together with Mojibake.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<form action="itemexcel.php" method="post" 
onsubmit='$("#datatodisplay").val( $("<div>").append( $("#ReportTable")
.eq(0).clone()).html() )'>
```

div or table what ever we want to use div or table should be id="ReportTable"

```
<table id="ReportTable" width="781" border="2"> Or <div id id="ReportTable">
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay"></td>
<td><input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel"></td>
</tr></table></div>

<input type="hidden" id="datatodisplay" name="datatodisplay">
<input class="bg" type="submit" value="Export To Excel">
```

itemexcel.php page

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=itemcode.xls');
// Fix for crappy IE bug in download.
header("Pragma: ");
header("Cache-Control: ");
echo $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"download.xlsx");
header("Cache-control: private");
```