# i need help on how to export to excel in php with utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, mysql, excel, encoding, utf-8

I have managed to export to excel from mysql database but MS_OFFICE doesn't 
 recognize greek characters.Please help.

Comment: the answers above didn't help me

Comment: You exported it incorrectly, so try again with different settings.

Comment: can you explain me the settings??

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, and it's already been flagged as off-topic. You'll need to ask somewhere else.

Comment: like where??please guide me

Comment: I reopened because the [_"dup"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639303/php-export-to-excel) neither addressed the same issue, nor was it satisfactorily answered.

Comment: Please provide the hex for some of the naughty characters.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using phpnyadmin export into “open office spreadsheet “ and then open it in excel